# Intersection of 2 lines in any given dimension?

Tags: geometry, vectors

Suppose I have two lines $p$<sub>1</sub>-$p$<sub>2</sub> and $p$<sub>3</sub>-$p$<sub>4</sub> in the following dimensions:

> 2D
> ($x$<sub>1</sub>, $y$<sub>1</sub>)-($x$<sub>2</sub>, $y$<sub>2</sub>) and ($x$<sub>3</sub>, $y$<sub>3</sub>)-($x$<sub>4</sub>, $y$<sub>4</sub>)

> 3D
> ($x$<sub>1</sub>, $y$<sub>1</sub>, $z$<sub>1</sub>)-($x$<sub>2</sub>, $y$<sub>2</sub>, $z$<sub>2</sub>) and ($x$<sub>3</sub>, $y$<sub>3</sub>, $z$<sub>3</sub>)-($x$<sub>4</sub>, $y$<sub>4</sub>, $z$<sub>4</sub>)

> 4D
> ($x$<sub>1</sub>, $y$<sub>1</sub>, $z$<sub>1</sub> , $w$<sub>1</sub>)-($x$<sub>2</sub>, $y$<sub>2</sub>, $z$<sub>2</sub> , $w$<sub>2</sub>) and ($x$<sub>3</sub>, $y$<sub>3</sub>, $z$<sub>3</sub> , $w$<sub>3</sub>)-($x$<sub>4</sub>, $y$<sub>4</sub>, $z$<sub>4</sub> , $w$<sub>4</sub>)

Or in a much higher dimension What would be a general matrix based formula to get  the point at which they intersect (vector based most preferably, if not anything that works would do).

Comment: It's rather unlikely that two random lines intersect at all in 3 or more dimensions (and not guaranteed in 2 dimensions).

Comment: they are not random lines, even if they are I am sorry to say this but I don’t see in anyway how your comment was any helpful despite the upvote to it. For context sake I am trying to get the point at which a coplanar line would intersect with another line from any planar face from my polytope. unlikely doesn’t mean it’s impossible even if they were random lines.

Comment: Comments are not meant to answer a question. That is what *answers* are for. The main purpose for comments is *clarifying* the poster's intent and addressing other issues in the post. The way your question is worded, it sounds very much as if you expected two lines to always or almost always intersect. Such a mis-understanding can often lead to difficulties when one does attempt to give an answer, as the questioner will have unrealistic expectations that interfere with their comprehension. Thus Greg Martin's comment was addressing this potential issue, and is quite appropriate.

Comment: my apologies then, I got the wrong impression about the intent of Greg’s comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line through $p_1$ and $p_2$ has the parametric formula $$t \mapsto p_1 + t(p_2 - p_1).$$ This establishes a one-to-one correspondence between all real numbers $t$ and all points on the line. Similarly the line through $p_3$ and $p_4$ has parametric formula $$s \mapsto p_3 + s(p_4 - p_3).$$

At the point where the two lines intersect, these are equal:
$$p_1 + t(p_2 - p_1) = p_3 + s(p_4 - p_3)\\
t(p_2 - p_1) - s(p_4 - p_3) = p_3 - p_1\\
P\begin{bmatrix}t\\s\end{bmatrix} = p_3 - p_1$$
Where
$$P = \begin{bmatrix}p_2 - p_1&p_3 - p_4\end{bmatrix}$$
is the $n \times 2$ matrix whose first column is the vector $p_2 - p_1$ and second column is the vector $p_3 - p_4$.

In $2$ dimensions, $P$ is square, and if invertible, the system can be solved as $$\begin{bmatrix}t\\s\end{bmatrix} = P^{-1}(p_3 - p_1)$$
If $P$ is not invertible, then the two lines are parallel, and either do not intersect, or actually are the same line.

When $n > 2$, the system is over-specified. Choose two linearly independent equations out of it, and solve them. Then check the solution against all the other equations to see if it makes them true as well. If so, it is a solution to the full system. If not, there is no solution. The two lines are skew. If you cannot find two linearly independent equations in the system, then the two lines are parallel and either do not intersect, or are in fact the same line.

Once you have the solution for $t$ and $s$, plug either value into its parametric formula to find the point of intersection.

Comment: much thanks, this was really what I was looking for, especially the latter part of the answer `when n > 2`